# I want to make a timer start counting down right after receiving a javascript response

Tags: javascript, html, timer, response

I want to make the timer count down just after receiving a quote from an api request. If user has not asked for the quote, the timer should keep set on the specified time (4 minutes in this case).

Here is the code I have so far for the timer:

```js
          function startTimer(duration, display) {
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

window.onload = function () {
    var fourMinutes = 60 * 4,
        display = document.querySelector('#time');
    startTimer(fourMinutes, display);
};
```

```html
        <section>
          <h6>Timer</h6><div><span id="time">04:00</span></div>
        </section>
```

And this is the code for getting the quote:

```js
async function getQuote() {
  if (
    !currentTrade.from ||
    !currentTrade.to ||
    !document.getElementById("from").value
  )
    return;

  let amount = Number(
    document.getElementById("from").value *
      10 ** currentTrade.from.decimals
  );

  const quote = await Plug.quote({
    network: "repl",
    fromAddress: currentTrade.from.address,
    toAddress: currentTrade.to.address,
    amount: amount,
  });
  console.log(quote);
  document.getElementById("to").value =
    quote.toAmount / 10 ** quote.to.decimals;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can to set your element "to" id in a `<input id="to" type="text">` then you can add addEventListener to `id="to"` that listen to change when you update it `document.getElementById("to").value = quote.toAmount / 10 ** quote.to.decimals;` when quote has changed so it will run `starttimer`

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var fourMinutes = 60 * 4,
    display = document.querySelector('#time');
  const input = document.querySelector('#to');
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    // Start timer
    startTimer(fourMinutes, display);
  });
 
};

function startTimer(duration, display) {
  var timer = duration,
    minutes, seconds;
  setInterval(function() {
    minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);
    seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

    minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
    seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

    display.textContent = minutes + ":" + seconds;

    if (--timer < 0) {
      timer = duration;
    }
  }, 1000);
}
```

```html
<input id="to" type="number" disabled />
<section>
  <h6>Timer</h6>
  <div><span id="time">04:00</span></div>
</section>
```

Here is what to change in your get quote

```js
async function getQuote() {
  if (!currentTrade.from ||
    !currentTrade.to ||
    !document.getElementById("from").value
  )
    return;

  let amount = Number(
    document.getElementById("from").value *
    10 ** currentTrade.from.decimals
  );

  const quote = await Plug.quote({
    network: "repl",
    fromAddress: currentTrade.from.address,
    toAddress: currentTrade.to.address,
    amount: amount,
  });

  let updateQuote = document.getElementById("to");
  updateQuote.value = quote.toAmount / 10 ** quote.to.decimals;
  updateQuote.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));


}
```

Comment: Thank you Cadmus, but there are some details.
1. The id="to" is already inside an input, and it is type="number", not type="text".

2. This input is disabled as users don't need it to type anything inside of it but only to receive information (the quote in this case, which comes in numbers).

3. There are two inputs, (both with type="number") after users enter an amount in input 1, the quote gets displayed on input 2, and is at this moment that the timer should start counting down immediately.

Comment: I tried with your code and it is not working:

document.getElementById("to").value = quote.toAmount / 10 ** quote.to.decimals;
window.onload = function () {
  var fourMinutes = 60 * 4,
      display = document.querySelector('#time');
  const quote = document.querySelector('#to');
  input.addEventListener('change', (e) =>{
      // Start timer
      startTimer(fourMinutes, display);
  });
};

Comment: @Dionisio I have updated my code i forgot to tell you to add `updateQuote.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));` to make active event change on input "to". Run code snippet to check the result.

Comment: thank you again, the code is better, nevertheless I think you still have not got the idea. I dont want to let the timer start counting down after a selected period of time. I just want it to count down after the quote displays in the input. This shoud happen after the users enters an amount in the enabled input. This does not work properly with the idea:

  // change input id="to" after five second
  setTimeout(function() {
    let updateQuote = document.getElementById("to_amount");
    updateQuote.value = 10;
    updateQuote.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  }, 5000);
};

Comment: I guess it should be something like this:


  // change input id="to" after five second
  setTimeout(function() {
    let updateQuote = document.getElementById("to_amount");
    updateQuote.value = getQuote().result;
    updateQuote.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));
  },);
};

Comment: Where there is no time for the timer to start counting down, and the value of the quote is not 10, but the result of the getQuote() function. Please let me know what you can get from this, best regards and thanks again.

Comment: @Dionisio Hi, The `settimeout` is just an example of the API quote result. That means when the value of input gets changed its starts to invoke 'startTimer()'. It you need it to start when it recive result of `getQuote` just add `  updateQuote.dispatchEvent(new Event('change'));`  when you change `<input id="to">)`. It will invoke 'startTimer()'. Take a look at the code i just change in your `getQuote` function.

Comment: Thank you. I'll let you know how it does now.

Comment: Hi @Cadmus, the timer works perfectly now, I was just wondering if there is any way to reset it to 4 minutes by pressing a button.

Comment: @Dionisio Yes, you can clear your Interval with `clearInterval`. Then set `<span id="time">` to `04:00` then start `startTimer()` again.

Comment: I have this function which successfully resets the timer but once it does, it starts counting down again and this is what I want to prevent (I want it to stay in 4 minutes if reset, at least until displaying a new quote again)

`function resetTimer() { 
timer = 60 * 4; 
};`